# Sublists in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to create a sublists of the list from the elements that satisfy the condition

fun (>0) [1,2,0,3,0] = [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]

Code for creating sublists:

```
power_list [] = [[]]
power_list (x:xs) = [x:sublist | sublist <- power_list xs] ++ power_list xs
```

Comment: Have you tried to solve it yourself? What's your thought process and where did you get stuck?

Comment: i created function for sublists and the i have stucked

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps to this problem: eliminating elements that don't satisfy the condition, and then creating sublists from the resultant list. Let's focus on the first part first.
There is a function that already exists for checking which elements satisfy a condition, but for the sake of learning you should try implementing it yourself.

Your `fun` should looking like this:

```
fun f list = power_list (keepSatisfyingElements f list)
```

As for `keepSatisfyingElements`, here's a skeleton of what your function should look like

```hs
keepSatisfyingElements :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
keepSatisfyingElements f [] = []
keepSatisfyingElements f (x:xs) = -- What do you do if `x` satisfies `f`, and what do you do if it doesn't?
```

Now the second part - creating sublists (there's actually already a function for this too, but I'm going to reimplement it here). The code you have posted does create every sublist of a list, but going by your expected output, that's not what you're looking for.
After some experimentation, you'd probably find out that it's easier to create the results backwards, i.e. `[[1,2,3],[1,2],[1]]` instead of `[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]`. So let's try that first.
First the base case:

```hs
power_list [] = [[]]
```

Now, what do we do if the list has an element? First, we keep the entire copy of the list

```hs
power_list lst = lst : ???
```

Now, we want to do the same thing again on the list - but this time without the last element. And there is a function to remove the last element of a list - `init`.

```hs
power_list []  = [[]]
power_list lst = lst : power_list (init lst)
```

The result isn't perfect though - `power_list [1,2,3]` gives us `[[1,2,3],[1,2],[1],[]]`. This is an easy fix:

```hs
properPowerList lst = tail (reverse (power_list lst))
```

And for the final function:

```hs
fun f lst = properPowerList (keepSatisfyingElements f lst)
```

---

*Note*: Like I said, there are already functions for what you want, `filter` and `inits`.

```hs
> import Data.List (inits)

> filter (>5) [2,4,9,7,27,93,5,1,10]
[9,7,27,93,10]

> inits [1,2,3]
[[],[1],[1,2],[1,2,3]]
```

And so you could write `fun` like this:

```
fun f lst = tail (inits (filter f lst))
```

Comment: @WillNess Oops...I saw the code for `power_list` and assumed that it worked and they were asking about filtering - I'll update the answer to cover that as well